# How to set the background screen as Wallpaper all the time?

Tags: android, background, wallpaper

Currently, I'm using this to show my application background as phone wallpaper.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);
```

But for some reason when I start my application by pressing the icon. It just shows the activity screen with the icons on the home screen. I didn't use dialog but it looks like a dialog because layout is just set that way. So I just want to show the wallpaper whenever this activity is running. But it only shows the wallpaper only after the next event occurs such as switching to different activity. I already put that code on `onCreate()` and whenever I do `setContentView()`..... Is there way to do such thing or there is just no way?

Comment: Reading it twice I'm still not completely sure what your problem is. Can you supply screen shots? (perhaps it sounds like a call to invalidate() etc. to redraw but really I'm not sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long search and trial and error. I've found the solution to what I wanted. It was just creating separate themes.xml file and just tweak the Theme.Dialog which is already defined in default android themes.xml. All I did was change the Animation part. Originally in android themes.xml the line looks like this.

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
```

but since modifying in android themes.xml doesn't take the effect. I just created my own themes.xml as I said above and just set parent as android:Theme.Dialog. And added a line like this.

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
```

Thanks for the help and I hope this solution helps others.

Comment: I came across this question trying to set the user wallpaper as the background for an app that has a very limited UI and an otherwise bland background. It is great that you can provide and accept your own answer, but perhaps you should have worded the question and / or title for what you found to be your issue. As is, this answer does not fit what is presented.

Answer (score 12):

For users of AppCompat, just use the following in your styles.xml, no need for code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code -

```
    rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.someid);
    //relative layout is my root node in main.xml (yours may be linearlayout)
    WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    Drawable d = wm.peekDrawable();
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable(d);// You can also use rl.setBackgroundDrawable(getWallpaper);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment rohit but I get null pointer exception at line rl.setBackgroundDrawable(d); I've put the code in onCreat() and added id for my root node in main.xml and changed RelativeLayout to LinearLayout since mine's LinearLayout.... and I just declared rl as global variable. LinearLayout rl;

Comment: I solved the null pointer exception problem but that code seems to set the background of the layout.... maybe I wasn't clear before... since my activity layout looks like a dialog, when I run the application it shows the dialog layout and dims the screen in the background below the activity... What I wanted was how to show the wallpaper in the dimmed screen without any home screen icons. The code I provided works after few events occur but I want it to work as soon as the activity happens and go back to home screen whenever activity is not active or just running in the background......

Comment: Nice that you find the answer.. Actually, I just got that code from android docs of wallpaper manager. I didnt come across such scenario. Thanks for sharing answer :) good luck

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, since it is a valid answer to the question in the title. Thank you for providing this answer, as others no doubt end up here with the wrong impression about what is being asked.