# Set device wallpaper to be the background for an activity layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't seem to get what is wrong with my code here for setting the device wallpaper to the background for the layout of the launcher activity. I Have tried to search this online for better code but what I have gotten so far is this one which causes an error:

---

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

MyLogin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login);
MyLogin.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
```

---

I would appreciate your help and concern on this issue

Comment: Mind to tell us which error you get? Possibly include the logcat in your question

Comment: Try this
`MyLogin.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);`

Comment: Btw, this code you posted works too.

Comment: Thank you @Psy Duck for your soultion. It worked like a charm

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. :) Select my answer by clicking the tick in front of it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will work for sure

```
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        MyLogin.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyLogin.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
            }
        });
```

And its true that you should use a descendant of ActionBar. Moreover you can opt for hiding the action bar later. Like this

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can set the style to the activity like this
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: thank you for your solutions please see below the one that worked form me

Comment: This works, but it's showing some default wallpaper that came with the phone, not my actual wallpaper.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to make system display wallpaper background for you.
There is [FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER) and [windowShowWallpaper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowShowWallpaper) attribute.

More examples can be found here:

- https://gist.github.com/heinrichreimer/a6c4b04cf77631857e50
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825818/87383

Comment: The gist worked for me with some adjustments (see the comment I left there). Other methods gave a different image instead of my actual wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use styles to use device wallpaper as Activity background. 
Use

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
```

or

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
```

As far as your code is concerned, since you didn't specified error you are having, most likely one is that you do not have `RelativeLayout` with id `login` in your activity layout `xml`

Comment: Got this: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Wait, I got this exception implementing your suggested theme.

Comment: @PsyDuck AFAIK `Theme.AppCompat` does not have `Wallpaper` style, so styles cannot be used. But I am successfully setting wallpaper as background with OP code.

Comment: thank you for your solutions please see below the one that worked form me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Two ways...

1. Go to that Relative Layout and inside `<RelativeLayout >` type `android:background="@drawable/yourImage"` for ex

> Give the Backround programatically like
>   MyLogin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login);
>   Mylogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);

Comment: thank you for your solutions please see below the one that worked form me

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me finally

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

    MyLogin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login);
    MySong.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
    }
```

The error was that when I run the application it just says The application MyLogin com.example.login has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

But after I changed setBackground to setBackgroundDrawable it now works.

Comment: I think this works only for normal wallpaper, no? Live wallpaper won't be shown, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
  MyLogin.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

instead of

```
MyLogin.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Although both will work depending on the device.

Comment: This works only for normal wallpaper, no? Live wallpaper won't be shown, right?

Comment: Live wallpaper is basically a video or gif file. So, it won't as WallpaperManager fetches a Drawable so at most it can fetch a frame out of it, that also I will have to test.

Comment: Live wallpaper is not a video or gif file. It's a whole app. It can show what it wishes, and it can even interact with the user.

Comment: What exactly is your requirment?

Comment: I just wanted to mention it. Using what you wrote won't always work. Users can use a live wallpaper instead of a static one.

Comment: Yes, but for Wallpapers it would and that's what asked in the question. Never claimed that this will work in all the cases. :)

Comment: A live wallpaper is a type of wallpaper. The user can set either a static wallpaper or a live wallpaper in the settings. It's completely legit. Also, when you use the API of getting the wallpaper, it will return you the static wallpaper, even if the user has set a live wallpaper to be the one to be shown.

Comment: Yes, it only fetches the Drawable.

Comment: Not only that, but I think it requires READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, or it will crash. Since it's not documented, I've written about it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110507691 .