# Set Current WallPaper As Application's Background in JetpackCompose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project in JetPack compose and I was wondering if there was a method of retrieving the current wallpaper on an android device and using it as the app's background. I am able to achieve this in XML using WallpaperManager but I cant seem to make it work in compose mainly because I cant pass a drawable to the Image composable. Any Ideas would be appreciated .

```
//this returns a drawable
 val wallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(LocalContext.current).drawable
```

How do I use it in compose to set background image

Comment: With traditional layouts, you can do this through theming without ever having to find the drawable of the wallpaper and use it, which would require app permissions. But I'm not sure how to do it with Compose. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839946/506796 There most likely is a way.

Comment: "I cant pass a drawable to the Image composable" -- look to see how `painterResource()` is implemented, or [create a custom painter](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/custompainter).

Comment: painterResource takes an Id. I need a composable that accepts a drawable

Comment: Composables don't work with drawables. Maybe you can do something like `Image(bitmap = someDrawable.toBitmap())`, but I think it would make more sense to load an image directly as a Bitmap if that's possible.

Comment: "painterResource takes an Id" -- correct. That is why I suggested that you look at the implementation of `painterResource()`, to see how it loads the image associated with that resource ID.

Comment: @Tenfour04 your suggestion helped. I will post the work around I used

Comment: You can just accept your own. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
val wallpaperDrawable = WallpaperManager.getInstance(LocalContext.current).drawable
val bitmap = (wallpaperDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

Image(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
    contentDescription = ""
)
```